# 3rd Party Custom Keyboard Settings text - 2nd line from bundle id?

Tags: ios, xcode, keyboard, custom-keyboard

I have an iOS host app with a Bundle Display Name "HOST" and an have created an enclosed custom keyboard with its own Bundle Display Name "My Awesome Emoji Keyboard"

On the Settings screen entitled "Add New Keyboard", The Keyboard is listed as:

```
line 1: HOST

line 2: end-of-host-bundle-id
```

1) How can I change the text of line 2? (The documentation doesn't mention that 2nd line: https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/Keyboard.html)

Bonus questions which I think are not possible...

2) How can I change line 1 to be just the keyboard name, "My Awesome Emoji Keyboard", instead of the host app name?

3) Also, on all other Settings pages, the Keyboard is listed as 
My Awesome Emoji Keyboard -- HOST
How can I change that text to be just "My Awesome Emoji Keyboard" without changing the Bundle Display Name of the enclosing app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrote to Apple about #1 and they suggested I file a bug/request. So maybe some day they'll make that field editable.